# How do I get Codenameone to capture video?

Tags: codenameone

I am using the following code to try to capture video with codenameone 2.0

```
        tProperty.setHint("name the property that is a media");
        final CheckBox cbVideo = new CheckBox("Video");
        final Button bCapture = new Button("Capture Media");
        final MediaPlayer mpPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        bCapture.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ect){
                try {
                    if (cbVideo.isSelected()) {
                        String value = Capture.captureVideo();
                        mpPlayer.setDataSource(value);
                        mpPlayer.setName(tProperty.getText());
                    }else {
                        String value = Capture.captureAudio();
                        mpPlayer.setDataSource(value);
                        mpPlayer.setName(tProperty.getText());

                    }
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        });
        cM.addComponent(tProperty);
        cM.addComponent(cbVideo);
        cM.addComponent(bCapture);
        cM.addComponent(mpPlayer);
        Command [] cmds = new Command[1];
        cmds[0] = new Command("Done") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                //do Option1
            }        
        };
           Dialog.show(editType, cM, cmds);
```

When running in the simulator, clicking on the CaptureMedia button, it will present the file chooser interface. But then I am unable to choose any file at all whether audio or video because the choose file button is diabled. 
How do I get to test the video capture in the simulator?

Comment: Actually this is a non-issue. The problem was that simulator was looking for an audio file when i thought it should be looking for video as a result of the cbVideo.isSelected(). Fixed now.

Comment: Not so fast. Still cannot get the video to play in the simulator. It is captured to a file but the player reports that the file doe not exist giving java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/jamesagada/.cn1/_var_folders__j_xsgymcmd1lsc5zqtg65ctlsm0000gn_T_temp6413969854734503786.mp4 (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a layout problem, you are adding the MediaPlayer component before the video was created, so it's preferred size is 0.
Try to place the video in the border layout center so it's preferred size is ignored and the player will have enough space to display.

Try this:

```
    final Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    final Button bCapture = new Button("Capture Media");
    bCapture.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ect) {
            try {
                final MediaPlayer mpPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                String value = Capture.captureVideo();
                System.out.println("Captured Video " + value);
                if (value != null) {
                    System.out.println("Playing Video");
                    InputStream is = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(value);
                    String strMime = "video/mp4";
                    System.out.println("Input Stream" + is.available());
                    mpPlayer.setName("bla");
                    mpPlayer.setDataSource(is, strMime, new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("reset the clip for playback");
                        }
                    });
                    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, mpPlayer);
                    hi.revalidate();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    );
    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, bCapture);

    hi.show();
```

Comment: Thanks Chen. You are right. I had to add                   mpPlayer.setPreferredH(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight()/2); to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a regression in playing local videos in the Codename One simulator although it should work on the device. The next update of Codename One will fix it but for now you can workaround it by playing from a stream which should work just fine.

Just use the `FileSystemStorage` class to get an `InputStream` to the video and invoke the appropriate playback code. Note that this is less efficient than the play via URL API so when the regression is fixed you should probably return to the URL based API.

Comment: I tried this but then it just does not do anything.

Comment: FileSystemStorage says file does not exist!

Comment: You always need to give a full path to the FileSystemStorage API and use the home directory

Comment: like this /Users/jamesagada/.cn1/_var_folders__j_xsgymcmd1lsc5zqtg65ctlsm0000gn_T_temp64139‌​69854734503786.mp4 ? this is the value from Capture.captureVideo(). Or should I use another command?

Comment: Not sure. How will I do that beyond doing an eclipse plugin update?

Comment: I have updated the client libraries. Modified `code`       System.out.println("Capturing Video");
String value = Capture.captureVideo();
System.out.println("Captured Video " + value);
if (value != null) { System.out.println("Playing Video");
InputStream is=FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(value);
String strMime="video/mp4"; 
System.out.println("Input Stream" + is.available());
mpPlayer.setName(tProperty.getText());  mpPlayer.setDataSource(is,strMime,new Runnable(){         public void run(){          System.out.println("reset the clip for playback");}});}} `code`. Same situation

Comment: Nothing happens. Am i making a mistake some where?

Comment: I think this relates to a bug that's already fixed but not updated. Try adding the prefix "file:/" to the URL returned from capture.

Comment: If I put "file:/", I get a file not found exception.

Comment: Is the file actually there? Does it say that with & without the file: prefix?

Comment: file exists. I used util.copy(is,os) to copy to new location which worked. I notice however that even when i try to play an existing video that it does not play i.e. the video does not show.

Comment: Did you try this on the device?

Comment: Tried out on Android. Same thing. It appears to play but no video shows. The video demo works though. However if i modify the video demo to capture and play, it stops working!